# Ubuntu 13.04 can't open software & updates / software sources

Tags: 13.04, software-center, macbook, software-sources, software-updater

I am using MacBook Air Mid 2012 running Single OS which is Ubuntu (Raring Ringtail). Its been a month I'm using Ubuntu and everything works fine, recently i can't open software & updates, when i click it does not shows up/open. When I open `Ubuntu Software Center`->`Edit`->`Software Sources`, again it does not open.

But when I open Terminal, type

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

it shows up/open. Am I in trouble? Does something goes wrong?

Note: Installing software from Ubuntu Software Center, installing from terminal, opening Software Updater works fine. Really love Ubuntu!

Output from terminal when I type:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center`:

```
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser-layer.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application

Software catalog update was successful.
```

[image]

Comment: Try to reconfigure `Software Center` once by : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center`. It would take sometime so wait.. Reply what did you get..

Comment: I edited the post, you can see the output from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

According to **warning** it seems to be a bug because some of the apps in repositories didn't updated/read correctly. As the post suggest you should consider to [launch a bug](https://login.launchpad.net/t5hk2TR6KLB68tZT/+decide).

But before that it is not bad to give a try to fix the problem. I suggest you to completely remove `software-center` and install it again, if you don't mind.

Please follow execute following commands in terminal to remove/install:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
sudo apt-get --purge remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -r ~/.config/software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install software-center
```

<sub>Just in a case, install [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) and check whether you'll be able to open `Software & Updates` through that. Also check whether you have some broken or residual pacakges.</sub>

I wish it would help you to fix your issue.. Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: Do exactly what you have told me. Nothing happened. Still, I can't open Software & Updates through dash, and from software center.

Comment: As I already mentioned, this is possibly a bug that you should launch. It would help developer to fix this issue.. :)

Comment: Great man. I ran all these commands here and I'm able to see "Software & Updates" again. Thank you very much. Awesome!

Comment: @kwoxer: My pleasure.. :D