# Getting error when try to run 'software-properties-gtk'

Tags: 18.04

**What I did**

In terminal, ran command

```
$ software-properties-gtk
```

**What I receive**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 175, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    's', (bus_name,), **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 158, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled: Process com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties received signal 11
```

**What I'm expecting**

To make the command error free

**Extra**

OS: Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
and anything else you want to know, I'll be happy to give you.
I tried a lot of solutions but none of them works.

Comment: where did this `/usr/local/bin/software-properties-gtk` come from? `which software-properties-gtk` please edit your question. and `readlink -f  /usr/local/bin/software-properties-gtk`

Comment: I forgot `snap list`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, something is broken in your tool-chain and you'll need to reinstall whichever package that is. The exception seems to suggest that there is something wrong with dbus. I would start by trying to reinstall that.

If you don't have aptitude installed first do:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then you can use aptitude to reinstall dbus.

```
sudo aptitude reinstall dbus
```

If that doesn't get you anywhere you may have to reinstall all the supporting packages. Take a look at the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789966/software-updates-crashes-and-will-not-open) for additional information, this is also where I found the info on reinstalling dbus which I mentioned seems to be the likely culprit.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work